# How to Get Difference Between Consecutive TimeStamps in BigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    DateTime
1     5-1-16 12:25:13
1     5-1-16 12:28:46
2     5-1-16 12:25:18
2     5-1-16 12:29:34
```

I want to find the difference in seconds between each consecutive timestamp for each ID. Is there a way to do this in BigQuery? I have several thousand records. I know I need to isolate the time from the date first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(DateTime))-TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(prev_DateTime)) AS diff,
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ID,
    DateTime,
    LAG(DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateTime) AS prev_DateTime
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS ID, '2016-05-01 12:25:13' AS DateTime),
    (SELECT 1 AS ID, '2016-05-01 12:28:46' AS DateTime),
    (SELECT 2 AS ID, '2016-05-01 12:25:18' AS DateTime),
    (SELECT 2 AS ID, '2016-05-01 12:29:34' AS DateTime)
)
```

> added

```
 SELECT
  ID, 
  TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(DateTime))-TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(prev_DateTime)) AS diff,
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ID,
    DateTime,
    LAG(DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateTime) AS prev_DateTime
  FROM YourTable
)
```

I noticed - looks like your DateTime field has unusual format - '5-1-16 12:29:34'
If this is a problem for you in implementing above query - you can try below one
Please note: for this query you need to [enable Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  UNIX_SECONDS(DateTime) - UNIX_SECONDS(prev_DateTime) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ID,
    DateTime,
    LAG(DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateTime) AS prev_DateTime
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ID, 
      PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S", DateTime) AS DateTime
    FROM YourTable  
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I have several thousand IDs and datetimes, how can I modify this query without typing out each id and datetime?

Comment: just use your table name after FROM. those few selects were used as an example for you :o) see addition to answer